# The talk of current amplifier vs voltage in audio?

Tags: audio

I cannot find any good scientific basis for the supposed benefit of designing low wattage current source amplifiers in lieu of the traditional voltage amplifier to drive a loud speaker. Given, this has mostly been discussed in the "Hi-fi" communities, can anyone shed light on the alleged merits of this?

Comment: Maybe this isn't the best place to ask what those crazy people think.

Comment: @ Andy aka--you're probably right...

Comment: @Andyaka LOL!  There's no good scientific basis for people buying $500 oxygen-free copper AC line cords either.....

Comment: Less oxygen used by audiophiles is always good.

Comment: In PA applications, this is ruled out since you parallel speakers/cabinets which requires a voltage source. For other applications where the speaker is fixed, you loose some damping because you have back EMF from the speaker which is presented as a voltage and a current source would not try to short it. On the other hand you get rid of power compression with current drive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many audiophool beliefs have no basis in fact, and this one is no exception.

Normal commercial loudspeakers are meant to be driven with a voltage signal, not a current signal.

You are probably thinking *"But what's the difference?  Whether I'm controlling voltage or current into a 8 Ω load, I get the same thing."*  That's true, but the gotcha is the speaker presenting a nice and constant 8 Ω resistance is the ideal, not reality.  There will be inevitable impedance changes as a function of frequency.  These are due to the significant inductance of the speaker coil, and various mechanical resonances.  The proverbial 8 Ω impedance is just a rough number that speaker manufacturers aim for but never achieve perfectly.

Given that the impedance of the load varies, you have to decide what the real signal is, voltage, current, or something else.  In this case voltage was picked for good reason.

When a frequency hits a resonance of a speaker, the impedance goes up.  With constant voltage as the impedance changes, the power into the speaker is inversely proportional to the resistance.  That means at resonance, less power is transferred to the speaker.  That's a good thing, because due to the resonance, the speaker will produce more sound for the same input power.  The lower power going into the speaker won't offset the whole frequency peak caused by the resonance, but it helps at least somewhat.  This also works in reverse for dips in the frequency response where the impedance goes down and the speaker becomes less efficient.

With fixed current into a varying load, the power is proportional to resistance.  That will make the uneven frequency response of a speaker even worse in most cases.

Even if without understanding the above mechanism, it should still be obvious to use a voltage signal since *that's what the speaker was designed for*.  Lots of engineering goes into the design of high end speakers, with significant effort to make the frequency response as flat as possible given the other constraints of size, cost, and the like.  The design strives for constant sound output power for fixed input voltage across frequencies.  This can and inevitably does come at the expense of flat frequency response for a fixed input current.

Current drive is simply not what the speaker was designed to work with.  When you run anything out of spec, you can't expect it to perform within the remaining specs.

Comment: I find it interesting that discussions of the difference in sound between tubes and transistors never seems to mention the different ways that different kinds of tube and transistor amps respond to differences in load impedance, since I would think that would almost certainly affect the sound the unit produces (whether the changes are desirable or undesirable would, of course, be to some degree a matter of taste).

Answer (score 2):

A crude approximation of a speaker is a magnetic field, in which a coil us able to move along the field lines and pulled back by a spring to some neutral position.

The position of the coil in the field (and thus the displacement of the speaker membrane) in the steady state is given by the position at which the magnetic force equals the retracting spring force. So the idea is that a given current sets a specific membrane position.

On the other hand, on an inductive element, the voltage determines the rate of the current change, so applying a constant voltage produces a constant membrane speed instead of a constant position.

This is the reason why some people consider driving a speaker with constant current the "more direct" approach, but it is accompanied by a lot of practical problems.

Answer (score 1):

*I cannot find any good scientific basis for....*

Then **maybe** there **is** no benefit ?

In **theory** the excitation of a loudspeaker voice coil has a direct relation to the coil current. But a voltage across a constant impedance also gives a constant current. Unfortunately loudspeaker impedance is usually not very constant, it is frequency dependant. So **in theory** current steering might be "better".

The fact remains that it is impractical, a current output amplifier would apply the maximum voltage it can deliver (it would clip !!!) when no speaker is connected or the speaker's impedance becomes too high.

Normal voltage output amplifiers only clip when overloaded when a large signal is applied. This behaviour is much more convenient.

The fact that it is **discussed** in the Audiophile forums but that you need to come here to get the practical engineer's point of view on the subject says enough about the audiophiles.